# Get Messages from Sqs using Reactive Programing

Tags: project-reactor

I'm new to software development and I want to get messages from aws sqs in nonblocking way using Reactive programming How do I do that

Answer (score 1):

The Java AWS SDK 2 has asynchronous clients built right into it - [`SqsAsyncClient`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/sqs/SqsAsyncClient.html#receiveMessage-software.amazon.awssdk.services.sqs.model.ReceiveMessageRequest-) is the one you'd need in this case.

You can use the `CompleteableFuture` this method returns as-is - of if you want to use project reactor specifically (as tagged in the question) then you can simply wrap the above in `Mono.fromFuture()` to return a `Mono<ReceiveMessageResponse>`.